# Like button doesn't like on profile until the url is submitted on the FB debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have placed a like button on every post page of the website.

To make sure things work out properly, I added all the required meta tags, Head tag, and html tags on pages which include,

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" onkeypress="keyfind(event)">

<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<meta property="og:title" content="xxxx"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="xxxx"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="xxxx"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="xxx"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxx"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxxx"/>
 <meta property="og:image" content="xxx" / >
```

Since we are sharing images, the og type was selected as article, just like 9gag.

So when i go to any of those page and click the like button, it clicks and the count increases successfully. However, When i check my Facebook profile, nothing shows up on profile as if I never liked it.

I tested it with multple facebook accounts, the count on the webpage kept increasing but none of the likes were shown on any of the profiles.

However, As soon as i put 1 url in the fb debugger, all the likes on that page suddenly appears on the profile.

for instance, if i like a page, and put the page's url 2 days later in the FB debugger, the link will appear on the profile saying [ FirstName LastName liked an article ] and shows 48 hours ago.

I understand that facebook takes a little time to scan urls, however, i have been trying to tackle this issue since a  week or so. Currently, i am surviving by putting all the urls one by one in the debugger.

Comment: Hm, interesting.  I'm not seeing that on my test app ( http://plooza.com/og/bar4.html ).  I clicked the like button on that page, then looked at my test user's timeline. It was visible and said "9 seconds ago". No re-scraping needed. Maybe your site is being throttled because it hit a spam threshold or other trigger.  I would try copying the like button (and other html) to another site and see if the issue remains on the other site.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you get anywhere with it?